# Z8410 DMA chip as GPU?

Tags: graphics, z80, performance, z8410

There are basically two ways to design a 2D graphics system:

1. Provide lots of hardware support in the form of tiles, hardware scrolling and sprites, to put together each frame on the fly from a small quantity of data, so you can have lots happening on the screen in every frame even if the CPU is slow. The Commodore 64 and NES are well-known examples of this strategy.
2. Provide a simple frame buffer that can store a relatively large quantity of data, and rely on the CPU (plus any support chips) to be able to move that data around fast enough. The Apple II and Amstrad 464 are well-known examples of this strategy.

The second strategy produces an elegant and flexible design, but has the disadvantage that if you want lots happening on the screen in every frame, you can get severe slowdown. For example, a 4 MHz Z80 can blit about 200K/second, which sounds like a lot but at 60 fps, it would be only about 3K per frame, and you really want something like 20K of frame buffer for good graphics without tiles or sprites.

It is said that the Z8410 DMA chip can blit much faster, up to 2 megabytes/second. Would it be feasible to use it as a sort of GPU, put it in a home computer and let it handle scrolling and suchlike for an order of magnitude speedup? If so, why was it never done?

It seems the answer is yes, doable! But a couple of people have pointed out it's not a full match for the Amiga's blitter, because it doesn't do bit shifting and masking, only byte transfers. This is true, but will be considerably ameliorated by using chunky pixels (as opposed to bit planes on the Amiga). Suppose we had one pixel per byte. The problem would disappear. Unfortunately that's not feasible on an 8-bit home computer, but suppose we have something like the low resolution mode on the Amstrad 464, two pixels per byte. Now we can move two pixels without bit shifting. Better yet, if we double buffer, each buffer can move two pixels without bit shifting, for a net effect of one pixel movement per frame.

Addendum: if the blit is for the purpose of horizontal scrolling, hardware scrolling - which I think is cheap to provide? - would also help.

Comment: I can offer that the Atari Lynx, designed in '86 or '87 even though it didn't get to market until '89, is a rare example of an 8-bit frame buffer and [scaling] blitter, using an 8kb frame buffer for 160x102, 4bpp. If you trace by design team rather than company, it's between the Amiga and 3do in the procession that started with the 2600. I couldn't speak as to a proper history of blitters prior to the Amiga though, so I think am unhelpful re: earlier machines. I suspect the 7800 was one though, but would need to check.

Comment: Having looked it up and found http://atarihq.com/danb/files/7800vid.txt it sounds like the 7800 is an interesting hybrid: there is a buffer and a blitter, but the buffer is one scan line long. Well, okay, there are two. One is being output while the next is being drawn to. So you're boxed in to having one line's time to draw one line, but there is a piece of hardware compositing bytes from a list of objects into a single buffer for later output.

Comment: When you say GPU, do you mean the chip that moves memory around (blitting things like sprites and screen memory contents) or the beast that actually creates the video signal?

Comment: @tofro The former.

Comment: I'm tempted to challenge your  "cheap to provide" statement in the last paragraph. That was what (years after the high time of Z80 HCs) delayed the Atari ST blitter chip so much it was introduced 12 months after the computer....

Comment: You may need to look into using Z180, It it had the best of all the Z80 Peripherals all in one IC, DMA, MMU, CTC, Serial and Z80 Core plusd speed, I used one variation that was internally clock at 33Mhz.

Comment: Scrolling is much better achieved with a movable buffer window for the display chip, so no data at all needs to be moved. This is how a _playfield_ is used on the Amiga you mentioned.

Comment: @Zac67 - yes, but sometimes you want to scroll just *part* of the screen.  Which is where display lists come in. :)

Comment: I'd venture a guess that the DMA peripheral chip was both more expensive and less flexible than just adding additional Z80 CPUs to the architecture to manage graphics. See my question about Galaga: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/how-did-z80-multiprocessing-work-in-the-namco-galaga-hardware

Comment: Discovered today: the upcoming ZX Spectrum Next appears not only to include a Z8410 implementation, but to scale its clock speed with the processor's. So in that machine, the DMA chip can, like the CPU, run at up to 24Mhz. Source: http://dailly.blogspot.com/2017/07/z8410-dma-chip-for-zx-spectrum-next.html . It also seems to have sprites and some sort of hardware assistance for scrolling so the test won't be entirely fair, but it might be interesting to watch what developers use it for in that machine as a potential partial answer.

Comment: What's the advantage over double buffer and switch video address,as the CPC464 does?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've been thinking about something like this myself, recently.  I wasn't planning on using a Z8410, though, but an Intel 8257-5.  This has a number of advantages:

- It has 4 controller channels rather than 2
- It was actually a cheaper chip than the Zilog chips

The interfacing to the Z80 wouldn't be quite as easy, but fundamentally the Z80 and the Intel 8085 that the 8257 was designed to integrate with were very similar chips, so shouldn't be too hard.

Why do I need 4 controller channels though?  The answer to that is that the DMA chip can perform multiple functions: it can produce the address generation logic for reading lines from a framebuffer, for reading sprites to overlay on the framebuffer, and for doing memory bulk transfers (the latter operation requires two channels, one to read and one to write) or operations for drawing into the framebuffer.  It handles taking control of the bus from the CPU and generating the signals that cause the CPU to wait if it needs to access memory (the scheme used by the 8085 and the Z80 for this look at first glance as though they are compatible, but more research will be necessary to be sure of this).  Basically, a single DMA chip can perform the same operations that are more commonly associated with a CRT controller chip, and provide useful additional functions in the same package, for a similar price.

This also lends itself to a more advanced kind of video controller: one that uses a display list.  In such a system, the processor writes a description of each scan line saying where in memory to assemble the various parts of the line from, and what formats they're in.  One DMA channel reads this description, and the second acts on it.  Display lists weren't exactly new (they were used in various Atari systems from the late 70s onwards, for example), but AFAIK there were no publicly available chips that could be used to easily implement them.  A DMA controller would probably be the easiest and cheapest option for a custom system that worked like this.

Comment: more channels are interesting one can be used for sound for example ...

Comment: The Nintendo DS uses this approach for (3D) display lists - you set the DMA controller's target address to the 3D processor's command FIFO, and tell it not to increment the address after each write.

Comment: It escapes me how any design like this would cope with masking, shifting and handling partial bytes - Stuff that is core functionality of a blitter chip.

Comment: @tofro: On a system which uses discrete Nx1 DRAM chips, masking and partial bytes could be handled by selectively enabling/disabling chips.  On Shifts could be handled with a barrel shifter and latch, wired so it would grab the bus contents on a single-address DMA read and output its contents on a single-address DMA write.  A two-channel controller programmed to alternate reads and writes would thus perform the rotate while transferring data at normal speed, though a non-aligned transfer would require two passes--one for the left half of every byte and one for the right.

Comment: @supercat Theres IMHO not much point in saying "Yes a DMA chip is suitable as a blitter if you do nearly everything that makes up a blitter in external logic". Your proposal might work, but sounds a bit complicated to me.

Comment: @tofro: If one wanted to build a graphics system using 1980s tech and couldn't use a purpose-designed blitter, use of a DMA chip along with some discrete logic to help it out may be more practical than using discrete logic for everything including address generation.

Comment: @supercat You mean it was so practical that everyone did it?

Comment: @tofro: Popular computers either didn't have any sort of graphical acceleration hardware, or were built in sufficient quantity to justify custom silicon for the purpose.  If one needed to build a workstation with a blitter and didn't have enough projected sales volume to justify custom silicon, using a DMA controller for the address-generation portion of the job would reduce the number of chips required.  I haven't studied enough low-volume-production designs to know to whether such chips were used (many designs that use a lot of discrete logic do everything with discrete logic)...

Comment: ...but if I were designing a Z80-based graphic system using period-correct parts and needed to support fast bitblt operations I can't think of a better way to do it./

Answer (score 18):

It has been already done for **ZX spectrum**.

see [Velesoft: DATA-GEAR](http://velesoft.speccy.cz/data-gear.htm)

[image: DataGear]

It has **DIL40** socket compatible pins at the bottom and it replaces **Z80** (so the bus is as short as possible). According to that site The bandwidth is around:

```
ZX128+ is 17.3 kB(17727 bytes) / frame = 865.6 kB(886350 bytes) / second
```

The higher bandwidth allows:

- fast scrolls
- **MultiTech** techniques to boost color resolution (8 pixel/attribute instead of 64 pixel/attribute)
- much easier doubling of screen resolution (256x384 instead of 256x192)
- easier and more precise border effects

Here **MultiTech** example (from my Emulator I got some timing issue with the **DMA** chip somewhere so there are few artifacts that are not present on real machine)

[image: multitech]

And the same image without **MultiTech**:

[image: normal]

Here grayscale **MultiTech** output:

[image: grayscale multitech]

And here preview of **DMA demo level2** (the choppy-ness is due to my **RT GIF** encoder, the emulation itself is smooth)

[image: DMA demo]

It goes smoothly even above 1000 sprites (If the magenta counter really is count of used sprites) ... without any over-clocking of standard **48K ZXS**

Comment: I sometimes wonder what my SAM Coupé could have been, had one of these been installed at launch. Something other than a machine that needs four or five frames to touch every pixel in its framebuffer, at least. I feel like at the time people were saying it would have added only £15 or so to the price — does that sound accurate?

Comment: @Tommy - Z80 DMA chips were sold at retail throughout the early 80s for about £10.  But IIRC the SAM Coupe was a Z80B machine running at 6MHz?  If so, the common Z80 DMA chips weren't compatible as they only went up to 4MHz.

Comment: @Jules there are also `6-8MHz` versions of DMA chip out there

Comment: @Jules yep, nominally 6Mhz, though in practice nowhere near unless executing in ROM due to crippling memory contention. So I guess that explains that.

Comment: Also, are you sure that multiple balls demo isn't just proving that you can copy an entire screen buffer and draw a single ball in less than a frame? That was a common demo technique for that: eight back buffers, replayed in sequence, during each loop moving a single ball onward and an endless stream therefore seeming to appear because of the ball you drew last time plus the one from time before plus the one from the time before that plus ... . Still impressive regardless, as obviously having bandwidth to move an entire frame buffer-sized block opens up thousands of options.

Comment: @Tommy hard to say we would need to disassemble and analyze the code to see if they are adding/not_clearing frames or really using many sprites. I was very curious about the MultiTech at that time so I incorporated the DMA chip and Data-Gear into my emulator. But sadly have some contention or timing problem somewhere (only with MultiTech as any other DMA stuff works without noticeable glitches) ... Btw If my memory serves well Data-Gear was not developed as graphic support but as a part of IDE/FDD/SDcard interface they where called MB01,MB02 or something like that.

Comment: I wonder how expensive bit shifting and masking would have been using late 1970s or early 1980s technology, if the chip had a clock input that ran 8x the memory clock speed?  While making complex logic functions run at 16MHz would have been difficult, things like shift registers could handle such speeds easily.  Having a device with a few shift registers, and logic so that feeding a byte into one would, for each of the next eight cycles of the high-speed clock, shift a byte through three mode-select shift registers and then, based on the values of those registers, either shift the source...

Comment: ...register and destination register, copying a bit, shift the source without shifting the destination, leave the source alone while shifting in 0, 1, the falling-out bit of the destination, or the falling-out bit of the source, would seem like it should simultaneously be relatively cheap and extremely versatile.

Comment: @supercat that sounds possible, CPU clock speed was usually divided from some higher one anyway and simple TTL logic ICs needed for this was way faster than CPU so I see it like just one or two address decoders,one latch (how many bits to shift) one binary counter one comparator and may be few NAND gates to handle the logic/control. AND/OR/XOR capability could be added similarly however those would need also buffer and 2 passes

Comment: @Spektre: I was thinking that control-bit shift registers would specify which operations to perform for each bit, thus making it possible to e.g. perform 2x expansion or contraction of binary data by having one shifter run on every cycle and the other run on only select cycles.

Answer (score 11):

Pushing large chunks of bytes around is actually a task a DMA chip is very good at.

The point is:

1. Pushing partial bytes around is a task a DMA chip doesn't help sooo much, there is a lot of the job still left to the CPU. A DMA chip is not capable of shifting the bits in a byte, which was one of the main operations when handling retro computers sprite drawing and scrolling.
2. A DMA chip cannot mask out bits on the "sprite margin". It always works on byte boundaries.
3. Pushing lots of small chunks around somewhat slows down a DMA chip (you need to constantly re-load DMA registers)
4. A DMA chip is not built to handle overlapping source and destination memory ranges, something that is pretty common in screen handling.

What follows is:

1. A DMA chip is *really good* at moving large chunks of around that have no holes in them and do not need to be shifted - In a typical home computer, however, to scroll by one pixel horizontally, you need to *shift* the bits in the byte - the DMA chip doesn't help at all here. It would be very good at scrolling and sprite-blitting vertically and in 8-pixel-increments horizontally on a Spectrum, for example, but that would look pretty jerky.
2. If you move rectangular (partial) areas of screen memory around, you typically have small chunks of contiguous memory to move, then a gap of a line length, then another chunk and so on - Moving sprites would require you to constantly re-load the DMA addresses once per each line of your sprite being transferred, each re-load a number of I/O transfers. Maybe a bit faster than moving with the CPU (depending on sprite size), but all in all not so much of an improvement.

Where a DMA chip would be really helpful would be in

- Saving whole screens to memory and back (no gaps, no shifts)
- Scrolling whole screen lines (or whole screen) up or down (no gaps, no shifts)
- Scrolling whole screen lines horizontally in increments of 1 bytes (on a Spectrum, that would be a jerky movement by 8 pixels only)
- Scrolling vertically (that always moves on byte boundaries). For vertical scrolling, you're running into the additional problem that a DMA chip cannot handle overlapping source and destination regions very well: It will always copy towards increasing addresses, so downward scrolling wouldn't work well without an additional buffer.

This is a little bit limited for a blitter chip.

With a different screen memory layout (8 bits/pixel) as in later computers, you would get rid of the shifting requirements and could really speed up graphics. But most retro home computers simply don't have that much screen memory.

You could also store your sprites bit-shifted (that means, shifted by one pixel into every possible horizontal position in memory), which would relieve you of the need to shift when moving sprites horizontally) but that would need 8 times the memory for sprites, not a very good idea for a home computer with limited memory.

A chip that would probably do exactly what you want/need the Z80DMA for was the *Blitter* chip that came in the Atari STs: It had exactly the functions you'd miss in a Z80DMA chip like shifting, masking and gap-jumps plus fast memory-to-memory copying.

As a conclusion, I think history has proven that if you built a mass-market computer with relativly high-end graphics, custom logic turned out to be much cheaper than off-the-shelf DMA chips with their limited capabilities extended by (again) custom logic. The Commodore C64, the Amiga, Atari ST and similar computers all went that way.

Comment: Fair point! Answered with an edit on the question.

Comment: If a computer used Nx1 DRAM chips it would probably not be particularly difficult to add gating logic to allow partial-byte writes.  Probably two chips and an inverter (use an 8-bit latch or flop with 3-state output to select which chips should be active when writing, and an 8-bit 3-state driver to drive all 8 chip-selects with the same pattern when not writing).  Shifting might be a little harder, but could still be practical in discrete logic.

Comment: @supercat Possibly, yes. But adding lots of external logic probably defeats the whole purpose of a standard chip - You'd be better off putting the whole shifting, masking, **and** DMA logic into a FPGA/CPLD today.

Comment: @tofro: Nowadays one would use an FPGA or possibly CPLD, but this is a retrocomputing q/a site which would typically favor "period-correct" solutions.  Bit rotation is probably more expensive than would be worthwhile, but if memory serves EGA provided it; I'm not sure how it was physically implemented, but it was there.

Comment: @supercat EGA didn't use a DMA chip, to my knowledge and also didn't provide any blitting functions - It relied completely on the CPU for shoving bits around. If you're looking for a (somewhat) contemporary chip, have a look at the Atari ST blitter chip mentioned above. The 8514/A "standard" was the first to my knowledge to provide graphics primitives on an IBM PC compatible card  as an API, to my knowledge (and, as such, the first "Graphics Accelerator Card" for the PC. That was, however, rather intended as a hardware copy protection.

Comment: @tofro: The EGA didn't include DMA, but it did have blit-ish functions.  When the CPU reads an address in the 0xA000-0xAFFF range, a 256K EGA will latch eight bits from each of four 64K banks.  Depending upon how mode registers is set, a write can update one byte in each bank based upon a combination of the latched data and the values that were written.  There are a lot of modes, some of which seem much more useful than others.

Comment: @supercat ...and none of this is even close to what you want to have for sprites or would even call a "GPU". My EGA card had registers that allowed you to select what planes (RGBI) were being written to when writing to video memory and the start address per plane to go into the display. That was about it. That was useful to shift whole planes around or implement a (horizontal) split screen and that was that. Nothing even close to blitting. EGA cards were a nice improvement over what was there before but had nothing that would be relevant to this question.

Comment: @tofro: While the EGA card was not designed to work well with DMA, it is an example of period hardware which performed allowed bitblt-style operations to be performed using a sequence of memory accesses without requiring that the device performing such accesses do any masking or bit shifting of its own.  A system which had an EGA along with a two-channel DMA controller which handle memory-to-memory transfers could have used such a controller to do BITBLT operations by programming one channel to read EGA address just before the other one wrote it.

Comment: @supercat Again: An EGA card wasn't able to mask or bitshift. No.

Comment: @tofro: On the EGA, GC register 8 is used to control the bit mask.  A read-modify-write sequence on an address will only affect bits in memory if the corresponding bit in that register is set.  Bits 0-2 of GC register 3 are used to perform bit rotation.  The design of the EGA makes it very awkward to use the masking and rotation functions (so the majority of graphics libraries never even bother with them) but someone thought it was practical to implement such things in hardware, and with a few cheap changes they could actually have been useful.

Answer (score 8):

Is it possible that you're using the here the term 'blit' as in Bit-Blit? If yes, than it's inaproptiate, as your examples are only about moving (byte) data. Moving is just one function of a bit blit engine. Beside logical operations, it also includes the handling od rectangular areas in a display wich are **not** (always) a consecutive series of memory cells (read, an icon or sprite is spread out over several screen lines which are wider than the image).

A (Z80) DMA can only move consecutive chunks of memory. To move something like an icon to a screen image, you would need to configure and start the DMA for each line. Unless we talk about icons half the size of a screen, the CPU will be faster in just doing the work by itself - especially when additional logic operations (like masking) are needed. There's a reason specific blitters have been designed. Standalone or as part of graphic chipsets.

A DMA as part of the graphics system only makes sense to handle the memory access and stream the video data toward the encoder. Like in two counter generating the pixel clock which is feed to the DMA-Request to fetch the according byte.

The only DMA alike chip I know that could be used as a blitter would be the 8089 IOP which in fact was already available in 1980. But maybe a bit more expensive than a 8410. Here some screen programm could run and do many operations quite fast, and at the same time generate all data for a video stream on the fly.

The 8089 can easy be interfaced with a Z80.

Comment: Out of interest, was just looking for a retail price for the 8089. Found one in [April 1982 Radio Electronics magazine](https://archive.org/stream/radio_electronics_1982-04/Radio_Electronics_April_1982#page/n123/mode/2up/search/8089) for $90 -- which comparing it against a Z80A-DMA at $28, or even $35 for an 8088 or $60 for an 8086 seems a bit expensive, but I guess they cost more due to not being all that popular.